# SonarQube no longer detects C# issues

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube

I upgraded my build agent to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and I noticed that C# code analysis issues are no longer reported.

I am using SonarQube 5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bogdan, the same happened to me.
You need to upgrade your C# plug-in to be at least version 5.3.1

Indeed, Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 introduced a breaking change in the Static Analysis Result Interchange Format (SARIF) generated by the C#/VB compiler. As a result the C# plug-in could not find any issue any longer. SonarSource reacted quickly by providing a bug fix version (5.3.1)
Note that this should not happen again as now SARIF has moved to version 1.0 (that happened in VS 2015 Update 3, and its versioning will be fully supported moving forward)

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, and the c# plugin 5.3.1 doesn't work either.  I even tried the 5.3.2 RC

Comment: @karoberts Did 5.3.2RC work for you? We appreciate all the negative or positive feedback on the request-for-feedback messages in the SonarQube mailing list.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam  No, 5.3.2 RC didn't help either

Comment: @karoberts could you please create a different post on the SonarQube google group? We'll need the SARIF report to find the root cause.